# Writing a tab completion script for bash

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script, autocomplete

I made a shell script that reads input from user and kills a process. But in bash if the user presses <kbd>Tab</kbd> key then bash suggests some `keyword` or `file` names. My script however doesn't suggest anything.

How can I enable tab completion for my script ?

Answer (score 2):

The easy way is to install `bash-completion` (or whatever else your distribution calls it), write a completion script, and put it in `/etc/bash_completion.d`.  A basic completion script looks like this:

```
have cancel &&
_cancel()
{
    local cur

    COMPREPLY=()
    _get_comp_words_by_ref cur

    COMPREPLY=( $( compgen -W "$( lpstat | cut -d' ' -f1 )" -- "$cur" ) )
} &&
complete -F _cancel cancel
```

This is for the `cancel` command from `cups`.  Read about `COMPREPLY` and `compgen` in the manual for `bash`, and adapt it to your needs.