# Bash script - auto complete for user input based on array data

Tags: bash, autocomplete, readline, read

In a bash script I'm reading some user input with `read`. Now I want to provide the possibility to auto-complete the input by hitting the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key.

Easy example: Let's say, the user shall type in a name from a limited domain. In the script I have an array containing all valid names, those should be included in the auto-completion-suggestions.

I already tried something with programmable completion, but I want the script to be portable, i.e., everything should be **in** this very script. Something comparable would be mysql - if you type `SELECT * FROM` and the hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> it shows all available tables in the database (and actually all columns).

Should work on Mac OS X.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Writing a tab completion script for bash](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/202417/writing-a-tab-completion-script-for-bash)

Comment: Thanks, but this is exactly what i don't want!

Comment: Agreed. @Guido I don't think it's a duplicate. The "duplicate" is about command line completion. This one is about tab completion at a `read` prompt. Similar, quite possibly, but definitely different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [rlwrap](http://utopia.knoware.nl/~hlub/uck/rlwrap/), a readline wrapper.

From `man rlwrap`

> rlwrap runs the specified command, intercepting user input in order to provide readline's line editing, persistent history and completion.

and from the Debian `rlwrap` package description:

> This package provides a small utility that uses the GNU readline library to allow the editing of keyboard input for any other command.  Input history is remembered across invocations, separately for each command; history completion and search work as in bash and completion word  lists can be specified on the command line.

A very simple example script:

```
#! /bin/bash

ynm=(Yes No Maybe)

reply=$(rlwrap -S 'Do you want to continue? ' -H ~/.jakob.history
        -e '' -i -f <(echo "${ynm[@]}") -o cat)

echo "reply='$reply'"
```

This uses `rlwrap`'s one-shot mode to run `cat` (to get stdin) but accept only one line of input.  `-o cat` is `rlwrap`'s recommended substitute for `read`.

Command-line history is stored in `~/.jakob.history`, and the completion items are in the bash array `$ynm`.

`rlwrap` expects a file as the argument to the `-f` option.  Fortunately, we can use process subsitution `<(echo "${ynm[@]}")` to supply an array rather than a file.

`-i` enables case-insensitivity for completions.

The `-e ''` stops `rlwrap` from appending a space after a successful completion (so that `$reply` ends up containing, e.g., `'Maybe'` rather than `'Maybe '` with a trailing space)

If you want a default already pre-typed on the input line, you could use the `-P` or `--pre-given` option - e.g. add `-P Yes` to the `rlwrap` command in the example script above.  The user would only have to hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> to accept or backspaces or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>U</kbd> to erase the default (as is normal for `readline` in emacs mode).

see `man rlwrap` for details and more options.  e.g. you can enable filename completion with `-c` or `--complete-filenames`.

Check if `rlwrap` is packaged for your distro (it is for Debian and probably Ubuntu/Mint/etc, at least) before downloading and compiling the source.

Comment: Thanks! I've been trying a lot of things now, but it won't work. Could you provide a minimal example?